# How do I run tKinter while running the normal function of the script is functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I made a script which detects pixel colors in the screen and sends key presses to the chosen window when it detects the right one. I made a hotkey to start and stop this little loop of detecting pixels, etc. I then decided I want to make it an exe and have the hotkey configurable, I started using tKinter and got a window and a label in it working, until I figured out that the script doesn't even function correctly or at all other than show the window (even pressing the hotkey). then I moved the `root.mainloop()` to place all script code in between `root = tk.Tk()` and `root.mainloop()` and nothing still functions. Anyone got any solutions to make the script still work with a UI. Also maybe a way to read the hotkey even while the window isnt focused(though I think itll work anyway but just incase tKinter might not allow it).

As requested here is the previous code where the window opened but the script doesnt function properly

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import random
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
import win32com.client
from pywinauto import win32defines 
from pywinauto.application import Application
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Fisher Version 1.0')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=150, height=200)
canvas.grid(columnspan=1)

hotkeyLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Key for start/stop")
hotkeyLabel.grid(columnspan=1, column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()

app = Application().connect(title_re="FiveM")
win = app.window(title_re = "FiveM")

#GREEN ZONE X:  959 Y:  337 RGB: (106, 150,   1)
#G ZONE region=(40,23,300,30)
run = False
#keyRod = ['rodKey']
#keyFood = ['foodKey']
#keyDrink = ['drinkKey']
#keyHot = ['hotKey']





def autofisher():
    while True:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pressg.png', region=(305,23,30,30), grayscale=False, confidence=0.7) !=None: #detects if g prompt shows up
            #shell.SendKeys("g")
            win.send_keystrokes('g')
            #print("YEssssS ITS HERE") #test for detecting fish prompt
            time.sleep(1)
        
        r, g, b = pyautogui.pixel(959, 337) #detects the green zone
        a, c, d = pyautogui.pixel(959, 340) 
        if 100 <= r <= 110 and 145 <= g <= 155 and 0 <= b <= 5: #detects if in green is showing
            #print("hi", r, g, b)
            #print("ijhabd", a, c, d)
            #win.send_keystrokes('e')
            for y in range(338, 350, 1): #detects if line in range
            #for x in range(954, 964):
                j, k, l = pyautogui.pixel(959, y)
                if 0 <= k <= 50 and 0 <= k <= 50:
                    #print("cauight") #test for detecting the black
                    #shell.SendKeys("e")
                    win.send_keystrokes('e')

while True:           
    if keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
        print("kijanbdsjokn")
        run = not run
    if keyboard.is_pressed('k'):
        #win.send_keystrokes(keyBind)
        print("keyBind")

while run == True:
    autofisher()

        
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    # thing to run
    q, w, e = pyautogui.pixel(209, 1042) #detects the hunger   
    if 55 <= q <= 70 and 55 <= w <= 70 and 55 <= e <= 70:
        #press 3 for food
        win.send_keystrokes('2')
        time.sleep(10)
        #press 1 for fishing rod
        #send_keystrokes('1')
    u, i, o = pyautogui.pixel(287, 1056) #detects the thirst
    if 55 <= u <= 70 and 55 <= i <= 70 and 55 <= o <= 70:
        #send_keystrokes('2')
        #press 2 for water
        time.sleep(10)
        win.send_keystrokes('3')
        #press 1 for fishing rod
```

and this was the modified

```
from cgitb import text
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import random
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
import win32com.client
from pywinauto import win32defines 
from pywinauto.application import Application
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Fisher Version 1.0')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=150, height=200)
canvas.grid(columnspan=1)

hotkeyLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Key for start/stop")
hotkeyLabel.grid(columnspan=1, column=0, row=0)

app = Application().connect(title_re="FiveM")
win = app.window(title_re = "FiveM")

#GREEN ZONE X:  959 Y:  337 RGB: (106, 150,   1)
#G ZONE region=(40,23,300,30)
run = False
#keyRod = ['rodKey']
#keyFood = ['foodKey']
#keyDrink = ['drinkKey']
#keyHot = ['hotKey']





def autofisher():
    while True:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pressg.png', region=(305,23,30,30), grayscale=False, confidence=0.7) !=None: #detects if g prompt shows up
            #shell.SendKeys("g")
            win.send_keystrokes('g')
            #print("YEssssS ITS HERE") #test for detecting fish prompt
            time.sleep(1)
        
        r, g, b = pyautogui.pixel(959, 337) #detects the green zone
        a, c, d = pyautogui.pixel(959, 340) 
        if 100 <= r <= 110 and 145 <= g <= 155 and 0 <= b <= 5: #detects if in green is showing
            #print("hi", r, g, b)
            #print("ijhabd", a, c, d)
            #win.send_keystrokes('e')
            for y in range(338, 350, 1): #detects if line in range
            #for x in range(954, 964):
                j, k, l = pyautogui.pixel(959, y)
                if 0 <= k <= 50 and 0 <= k <= 50:
                    #print("cauight") #test for detecting the black
                    #shell.SendKeys("e")
                    win.send_keystrokes('e')

while True:           
    if keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
        print("kijanbdsjokn")
        run = not run
    if keyboard.is_pressed('k'):
        #win.send_keystrokes(keyBind)
        print("keyBind")

while run == True:
    autofisher()

        
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    # thing to run
    q, w, e = pyautogui.pixel(209, 1042) #detects the hunger   
    if 55 <= q <= 70 and 55 <= w <= 70 and 55 <= e <= 70:
        #press 3 for food
        win.send_keystrokes('2')
        time.sleep(10)
        #press 1 for fishing rod
        #send_keystrokes('1')
    u, i, o = pyautogui.pixel(287, 1056) #detects the thirst
    if 55 <= u <= 70 and 55 <= i <= 70 and 55 <= o <= 70:
        #send_keystrokes('2')
        #press 2 for water
        time.sleep(10)
        win.send_keystrokes('3')
        #press 1 for fishing rod

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried yet

Comment: @Tanay yep done, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this works:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
from pywinauto.application import Application
import tkinter as tk
import threading
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Fisher Version 1.0')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=150, height=200)
canvas.grid(columnspan=1)

hotkeyLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Key for start/stop")
hotkeyLabel.grid(columnspan=1, column=0, row=0)

app = Application().connect(title_re="FiveM")
win = app.window(title_re="FiveM")

# GREEN ZONE X:  959 Y:  337 RGB: (106, 150,   1)
# G ZONE region=(40,23,300,30)
run = True


# keyRod = ['rodKey']
# keyFood = ['foodKey']
# keyDrink = ['drinkKey']
# keyHot = ['hotKey']


def autofisher():
    while True:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pressg.png', region=(305, 23, 30, 30), grayscale=False,
                                    confidence=0.7) != None:  # detects if g prompt shows up
            # shell.SendKeys("g")
            win.send_keystrokes('g')
            # print("YEssssS ITS HERE") #test for detecting fish prompt
            time.sleep(1)

        r, g, b = pyautogui.pixel(959, 337)  # detects the green zone
        a, c, d = pyautogui.pixel(959, 340)
        if 100 <= r <= 110 and 145 <= g <= 155 and 0 <= b <= 5:  # detects if in green is showing
            # print("hi", r, g, b)
            # print("ijhabd", a, c, d)
            # win.send_keystrokes('e')
            for y in range(338, 350, 1):  # detects if line in range
                # for x in range(954, 964):
                j, k, l = pyautogui.pixel(959, y)
                if 0 <= k <= 50 and 0 <= k <= 50:
                    # print("cauight") #test for detecting the black
                    # shell.SendKeys("e")
                    win.send_keystrokes('e')

def keyboard_press():
    global run
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
            print("kijanbdsjokn")
            run = not run
        if keyboard.is_pressed('k'):
            # win.send_keystrokes(keyBind)
            print("keyBind")

def runFunction():
    while run == True:
        autofisher()

def main_thing():
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        # thing to run
        q, w, e = pyautogui.pixel(209, 1042)  # detects the hunger
        if 55 <= q <= 70 and 55 <= w <= 70 and 55 <= e <= 70:
            # press 3 for food
            win.send_keystrokes('2')
            time.sleep(10)
            # press 1 for fishing rod
            # send_keystrokes('1')
        u, i, o = pyautogui.pixel(287, 1056)  # detects the thirst
        if 55 <= u <= 70 and 55 <= i <= 70 and 55 <= o <= 70:
            # send_keystrokes('2')
            # press 2 for water
            time.sleep(10)
            win.send_keystrokes('3')
            # press 1 for fishing rod

def starts():
    autofisherT = threading.Thread(target=autofisher)
    keyboardT = threading.Thread(target=keyboard_press)
    runT = threading.Thread(target=runFunction)
    mainThingT = threading.Thread(target=main_thing)

    autofisherT.start()
    keyboardT.start()
    runT.start()
    mainThingT.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but no it doesnt, and sorry this is my first ever script so sorry if its a mess. But yeah as I said it doesnt work, any idea why? and also do you mind explaining how the autofisherT.start() does and why is it the way it is thanks.

Comment: @OGXirvin Your code had to many infinite loops so it may be not responding on running. So instead of using them use `Multithreading`

Comment: would it be dumb to put them all on the same loop?

Comment: no it will not be but it will take more time to do things and i was thinking to answer quickly and i did so 